# Javascript : Find the difference between 2 objects and return only keys

Tags: javascript, object, difference

I would like to find the difference of 2 objects and get only its keys that are updated and return them.

I have used `deep-diff`, `object-diff` npm library. but it is not working.

How can I solve this ?

I just want keys that are being changed. no matter they are updates, added or deleted.

Below is the code I have tried.

```js
const diff = require("deep-object-diff").diff;

let oldData = {
  name: 'ABC',
  age: 20,
  marks: [20, 50, 40, 30],
  hobbies: ['playing', 'reading']
}

let newData = {
  name: 'XYZ',
  age: 20,
  marks: [20, 40, 80, 30]
}

console.log(diff(oldData, newData));
```

So I want keys that are being changed like `name` , `marks` , `hobbies`.

Any help would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want differences of the keys in the objects, or all the differences, or changes when it is updated deleted etc. ?

Comment: I just want keys that are deleted or updated or added. because from the front end , I will send the array of **update** with only those keys that are updated or added or deleted.

Answer (score 1):

```
let setA = new Set(Object.values(oldData))
let setB=  new Set(Object.values(newData))
```

These will make arrays with your old and new values and make them `Set` afterwards. By the help of Set method, we can locate the differences

```
function difference(setA, setB) {
    let _difference = new Set(setA)
    for (let elem of setB) {
        _difference.delete(elem)
    }
    return _difference
}
let differenceArray = Array.from(_difference); // making Array from a Set
let differenceObject = Object.assign({},differenceArray)
```

Now we made an object which has keys that are just indexes(0,1,2..etc), values are the items of differenceArray. You got the values that changed, now we need to find the keys belong to these values in the object at the start (oldData)

```
 let oldData = {
  name: 'ABC',
  age: 20,
  marks: [20, 50, 40, 30],
  hobbies: ['playing', 'reading']
}

let newData = {
  name: 'XYZ',
  age: 20,
  marks: [20, 40, 80, 30]
}


let setA = new Set(Object.values(oldData))
let setB=  new Set(Object.values(newData)) 


function difference(setA, setB) {
    let _difference = new Set(setA)
    for (let elem of setB) {
        _difference.delete(elem)
    }
    return _difference
}
let differenceArray = Array.from(difference(setA, setB)); // making Array from a Set
let differenceObject = Object.assign({},differenceArray)  


const keysArray = [];
for (let value of Object.values(differenceArray)) {
  keysArray.push(Object.keys(oldData).filter(key => oldData[key] === value));
}


console.log(keysArray)  // 0: ["name"] 1: ["marks"] 2: ["hobbies"]
```

`keysArray` is the array consisting of the keys that changed

Comment: thank you for your answer. it's not working.

Comment: @XperiaReno I edited the answer. Can you try now

Comment: not working again. I get all the array with keys. my object might be vary. so I need to handle any case that occurs. the example I have set in my question is just a dummy example. not a real one.

Comment: I think this solutions is a good starting point, but you need to handle nested objects as well.

Comment: @John You have a point, I will take a look again

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that the objects will not have nested objects, I would extract the keys from the objects in a separate array like this

```
const allKeys = [...Object.keys(oldData),...Object.keys(newData)];
// TODO remove duplicate keys
```

then I would compare the value in both objects for each key, and add the key with a difference in an array

```
const changedKeys = [];
allKeys.forEach(key => {
 if(oldObj.hasOwnProperty(key) && newObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
  if(Array.isArray(oldObj[key])){
    // TODO loop the arrays and compare the difference
    // Wee need to do that because ['2'] === ['2'] means false.
  } else if(oldObj[key] !== newObj[key]) {
    changedKeys.push(key);
  }
 } else { // means the key was deleted 
  changedKeys.push(key);
 }
});
```

then your result is the changedKeys array.

NOTE: I wrote this without testing, bugs might be present. Also, if the objects contain other objects, we would need to think of a recursive strategy instead.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Object might be vary. there might be arrays inside of object. also nested object will there , too.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `for in` syntax.

```
for (let prop in first_obj){
    if(prop !== second_obj){
    return [Object.keys(first_obj),Object.keys(second_obj)]
  }
}
```

the return of this function will be or undefine - they equal, or array with two arrays onside - each one - an array of the keys of one object